# Type error : Cannot read property 'EVENT' of undefined

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, gulp, typeerror

I replaced the old version of the project with a new one - from https://wdfiles.ru/27Bx6 (old version) to https://wdfiles.ru/27Bx8 (last version). As a result I got an error

[gulperror1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKW3i.png)

[gulperror2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxGb4.png)

Tell me how to fix it.

I want that someone help me with error.

content content

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.